# Who is the “close bosom-friend of the maturing sun”?

Tags: meaning, poetry, john-keats

John Keats, in his ode ["To Autumn"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44484/to-autumn), writes

> Season of mists and mellow fruitfulness,
> Close bosom-friend of the maturing sun.

Who is the close bosom-friend of the maturing sun?

Comment: Have you looked at the title of the poem?

Answer (score 6):

The ode is titled ‘To Autumn’, which means that it is *addressed to Autumn*, as if the season were a person capable of listening to the speaker. This [personification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personification) is clearest in the second stanza, where the speaker directly addresses Autumn as “thee”:

> Who hath not seen **thee** oft amid thy store?
>     Sometimes whoever seeks abroad may find
> **Thee** sitting careless on a granary floor,
>     **Thy** hair soft-lifted by the winnowing wind;
> Or on a half-reap'd furrow sound asleep.
>     Drows'd with the fume of poppies, while **thy** hook
>         Spares the next swath and all its twined flowers:
> And sometimes like a gleaner **thou** dost keep
>     Steady **thy** laden head across a brook;
>     Or by a cyder-press, with patient look,
>         **Thou** watchest the last oozings hours by hours.
>
> <sub>John Keats (1820). ‘[To Autumn](https://archive.org/details/dli.granth.35936/page/136/mode/2up)’. In *Lamia, Isabella, the Eve of St Agnes, and Other Poems*, p. 138. London; Taylor and Hessey.</sub>

In this stanza Autumn is personified in several guises appropriate to the season. First, as a store-keeper in a granary where the harvest is gathered and the grains are [threshed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnowing) and [winnowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshing). Second, as a reaper sleeping after the hard work of cutting the corn, like the harvesters in “[Noon, Rest from Work](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Noon,_rest_from_work_-_Van_Gogh.jpeg)” by Vincent Van Gogh (below). The “hook” in the poem, that “spares the next swath” because the reaper has fallen asleep, is a [sickle or reaping-hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sickle) like the ones in the painting.

[image: Two blue-clad peasants lie asleep in the shade of a hay-rick in a bright orange reaped field under a dark blue sky. Their shoes and reaping-hooks lie beside them. A cart stands idle by another rick and two horses graze nearby.]

Third, Autumn is personified as a [gleaner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleaning), wading through a stream with head supporting a bundle of gleanings (that is, crops that had been dropped or scattered by the harvesters). Fourth, as a cider-maker watching the juice drip from the apples in the [cider press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_press#Cider_press).

Going back to the first stanza, we can see that it works in much the same way: Autumn is addressed as the “season of mists” in the first line, and as the “close bosom-friend of the maturing sun” in the second. A “bosom-friend” is “a specially intimate or beloved friend” and “maturing” means “bringing something to maturity” (both definitions from the *OED*), as the sun does to the crops in Autumn.

Comment: And I always assumed that Keats was saying that the sun aged as the year progressed, and so "maturing sun" meant that it would soon reach its decrepit stage in winter.

Comment: @PeterShor: Both ideas are present, I think — the aging of the year as well as the crops.